# CMake not adding preprocessor definitions for ASM_MASM

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, masm

In build system generated (Visual Studio 2017 Generator) with the following cmake, the 'test.asm' source file isn't compiled with the preprocessor definition MY_MASM_DEFINITION:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project("test")

enable_language(CXX)
enable_language(ASM_MASM)

add_library(Problem STATIC "test.asm")

target_compile_definitions(Problem PUBLIC "MY_MASM_DEFINITION")
```

The same is true if I set `CMAKE_ASM_MASM_FLAGS`, or use `set_target_properties`.

It does work if I use `set_source_files_properties`, but setting this on each source file will not work well in our build system.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a workaround other than using `set_source_files_properties`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the CMake "add_definitions" method?

Comment: Submitted a CMAKE bug request. Looks like they'll have this fixed in the next release. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24289