# Cmake ASM_MASM language not adding target_compile_options() to the MASM ml.exe command

Tags: cmake

When trying to assemble a MASM project using cmake version 3.24.3, the `target_compile_options()` below

```
if(WIN32)
target_compile_options(HelloWorld
    PUBLIC
        /DBUILD_HelloWorld
        /FlHelloWorld.lst
)
target_link_options(HelloWorld
    PUBLIC
        /SUBSYSTEM:Console,6.01
        /SAFESEH:NO
)
...
```

are not added to the MASM command

```
[Build:x86] ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"HelloWorld.dir\Debug\CodeBaseEND.obj" /D"CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"" ...
```

However, during the linking phase, the `target_link_options()` are added

```
[Build:x86] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE ... /SAFESEH:NO /SUBSYSTEM:Console,6.01
```

The root `CMakeLists.txt` file has these languages defined

```
project(HelloWorld VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX ASM_MASM)
```

Any ideas why the compile options are omitted or where the fix might be?

**EDIT**

Seems related to [CMake not adding preprocessor definitions for ASM_MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726489/cmake-not-adding-preprocessor-definitions-for-asm-masm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using `set_source_files_properties`

```
set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/asm/helloWorld.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/DBUILD_HelloWorld /FlHelloWorld.lst")
```

The options were correctly added

```
[Build:x86] ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"HelloWorld.dir\Debug\helloWorld.obj" /D"CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"" /D"BUILD_HelloWorld" /Fl"HelloWorld.lst" ...
```

To apply to multiple unique asm files

```
foreach(FILE {PROJECT_SOURCES})
    get_filename_component(FILENAMEONLY ${FILE} NAME_WLE)
    set_source_files_properties(${FILE} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Fl${FILENAMEONLY}.lst /DBUILD_{BINARY_NAME}")
endforeach()
```

Still not sure why `target_compile_options` does not work?

```
target_compile_options(HelloWorld
    PUBLIC
        /DBUILD_HelloWorld
        /FlHelloWorld.lst
)
```

Submitted a bug report to CMAKE: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24289